# data in correct json format

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am working on a feature of my website where I need to trigger an ajax call on the click of button. I am receiving data in this format:

```
Object {
    name: "abc",
    category_id: "1"
}
```

I want a result like this:

```
{
    "list" : [
        {
            "name" : "xyz",
            "category_id" : "1"
        }, {
            "name" : "abc",
            "category_id" : "11"
        }
    ]
}
```

my server side code is:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die(mysqli_error());
$name = $_GET['name'];
$sql = "SELECT * from test_search where name = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $category = $row['category_id'];
}
$data = array("name" => $name , "category_id" => $category );
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Is the 's' at the end of your code intentional?

Comment: I'm assuming this is just testing but - don't use this code in production without escaping user submitted data. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before, you were assigning $row array items to variables, and then not using them until after the loop. After the loop, you used those variables, but it would only have the last values. You must append your items to an array ('list') inside of your array and then `json_encode()` your result from the loop to get the desired effect.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die(mysqli_error());
$name = $_GET['name'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$sql = "SELECT * from test_search where name = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$data_array = array('list' => array());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data_array['list'][] = array("name" => $row['name'], "category_id" => $row['category_id'] );
}
echo json_encode($data_array);
?>
```

Untested code, apologies for any syntax errors.

I would also like to point out that your code is open to [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Follow the link to the PHP Manual to learn more about these and how to prevent them.

Comment: You're almost there. `array('list');` doesn't indicate a `list` index, it means the array contains a `list` element. The correct array declaration should be `$data_array = array();`.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Apologies, haven't worked with JSON for a while. Editing answer :)  Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: `$data_array['list'][]` was correct, NTL upvote from me. :-)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul OHHH, stupid me! Yes, I see what you were saying!

Comment: @RajdeepPaul When you added the list index back though, you forgot to add the open and close brackets to append to the inner array. I corrected. My mistake previously had been simply adding 'list' as a string item inside instead of an index to the parent array.

Comment: It doesn't matter actually, both the syntax are correct.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Well, without the `[]` after `$data_array['list']` OP would have same problem as before ;)

Comment: Oh, I thought you're talking about this statement, `$data_array = array('list' => array());`. See [http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38639649/3](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38639649/3), I had added `[]` after `$data_array['list']`. :-)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul You're right :) Thanks for your help reviewing my code

Answer (score 1):

You need to push $name and $category variables into another array - currently you're simply overriding those values in your while loop.

Do something like:

```
$list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $list[] = array('name'=>$row['name'], 'category_id'=>$row['category_id']);
}
$data = array('list'=>$list);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a read about PHP arrays here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Also before you jump straight to `json_encode($data)`, try `var_dump($data)` see what you're working with.

You need to build the array in your while loop,

```
$data = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $data['list'][] = [
      'name' => $row['name'],
      'category' => $row['category']
   ]
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Untested, but should give you what you need.